# Dockerfile not reading build arg or secret from file/stdin but works when hardcoded

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, github-package-registry

I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine
RUN mkdir /app && chown -R node:node /app
WORKDIR /app
USER node
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=ghtoken echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=$(cat /run/secrets/ghtoken)" > ~/.npmrc
COPY package.json yarn.lock .npmrc ./
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn install --only=dev
COPY --chown=node:node . .
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

This is a nextjs application and it has a private node module as a dependency which is hosted on GitHub NPM Registry. GitHub requires a personal access token for installing private node modules. So I cannot hardcode the token in the `~/.npmrc` file. I have two options: a) Pass the token via build arg 2) Use docker secrets. Unfortunately neither of these works for me. In line 5 of the Dockerfile, you can see that I am expecting a secret called `ghtoken` which I am loading from a file called `secret.txt` when running the build command:

```sh
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build . --secret id=ghtoken,src=secret.txt -t dashboard:latest --no-cache
```

This doesn't work. I get 401 unauthorized from GitHub's end. For some reason, the Dockerfile acts as if I didn't pass any secret at all.

If I change line 5 from this:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=ghtoken echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=$(cat /run/secrets/ghtoken)" > ~/.npmrc
```

...to this:

```
RUN echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<Real-Token-Here>" > ~/.npmrc
```

...then it works.

Similarly, if I go for the build arg approach, with a slight modification to my Dockerfile:

```
ARG GHTOKEN
FROM node:14-alpine
RUN mkdir /app && chown -R node:node /app
WORKDIR /app
USER node
RUN echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=$GHTOKEN" > ~/.npmrc
COPY package.json yarn.lock .npmrc ./
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn install --only=dev
COPY --chown=node:node . .
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

...and pass the GHTOKEN as the build arg:

```
docker build --build-arg GHTOKEN=<Real-Token-Here> . -t dashboard:latest --no-cache
```

...then I get 401 Unauthorized again. If I change line 6 from this:

```
RUN echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=$GHTOKEN" > ~/.npmrc
```

...to this:

```
RUN echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<Real-Token-Here>" > ~/.npmrc
```

I don't get errors. Apparently, my Dockerfile cannot read from the build arg or secret. How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**
The ARG approach was not working because I was using the ARG statement before the FROM statement. If I update the first two lines to look like this:

```
FROM node:14-alpine
ARG GHTOKEN
```

...then the token is properly retrieved. But I'm still in the dark why the docker secret approach wouldn't work. Besides, this arg passing approach is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

[will advise you not to use build arguments for passing secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg):

> **Warning:** It is not recommended to use build-time variables for passing secrets like github keys, user credentials etc. Build-time variable values are visible to any user of the image with the `docker history` command.

maybe you just need to take a different approach, such as:

1. create `.npmrc` file dynamically outside of your container
2. spin-up a vanilla node container and mount `.npmrc` and `node_modules` directory or a volume
3. run npm within the container

at this stage, you have the `node_modules` directory/volume ready and you can mount\copy it to your application container\image.

or... (you should do it wisely, do the file won't be stored in a layered cache)

1. create `.npmrc` file dynamically outside of your container
2. copy `.npmrc` into your application container
3. run npm
4. delete the `.npmrc` file from the container